# How to integrate Google Meet into an Iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, google-meet

I am trying to use Google Meet on my website using the `<iframe>` tag but the problem is that the iframe says `meet.google.com` refused to connect. And as far as my research goes I couldn't find an official API/SDK/whatnot to integrate Google Meet directly into my website. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://support.google.com/meet/thread/45737634/how-do-i-embed-a-meeting-as-iframe-please-note-i-do-not-want-stream-to-be-embedded?hl=en&msgid=45737634

According to the replies in this link, you can't

Comment: They do allow it but it should be used in a new tab. At least that is what one of the comments said

Comment: Yes, I just saw and tried that. Anyways, thanks for the help. I am really disappointed and surprised as to why Google Meet, first doesn't allow it to be embedded into iframes, well that could be because of security issues but, second, doesn't even have a Web SDK or API, while literally, every other service does, say, for example, Zoom.

Comment: fyi, there is a feature request on Google's issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/289696532

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very easy, you can integrate the Google Meet URL in the iframe.

Here is the code:

```html
<iframe src="https://meet.google.com/vof-pnug-wxk" height="800" width="800"  allow="camera;microphone">></iframe>
```